# adaptive math newcommand for indices

Tags: macros, xstring, xspace

I have defined a command to add a star as the power to the input variable.
It has to be in an adaptive way that if the input has indices, star is added to the main parameter and not the whole input.
In addition, I have parameters which i use in the text which are also defined as commands and require `xspace`.
However, use of xspace breaks the compilation.
Here is the snippet which works at overleaf:

```
\documentclass{article}
%\usepackage{xspace}
\usepackage{xstring}
\newcommand{\lien}{\ensuremath{E}\xspace}
\newcommand{\ih}{\ensuremath{I_{h}}\xspace} 
\newcommand{\atref}[1]{%
  \IfSubStr{#1}{_}{%
  \ensuremath{\StrBefore{#1}{_}_{\StrBehind{#1}{_}}^*}\xspace%
  }{\ensuremath{{#1}^*}\xspace %
  }
}

\begin{document}

\atref{\lien} and \atref{\ih} some more text.

\end{document}
```

As said, addition of `\usepackage{xspace}` kills it.

Comment: This does not compile for me, with or without the `\usepackage{xspace}`.

Comment: It's of course purposeless to use `\xspace` in the definition of `\atref`, which has a mandatory argument. You're complicating your own life by using `\xspace` and `\ensuremath`; better to just use `$...$` when math is involved.

Answer (score 1):

I have found out where it goes wrong, but have no idea how to solve it.

I made another simple code to check that:

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand{\cur}{\ensuremath{I}}
%\newcommand{\cur}{\ensuremath{I}\xspace}

\newcommand{\tess}[1]{\IfSubStr{#1}{I}{true}{false}\xspace}

\begin{document}
This is to check the command \tess{\cur}.
\end{document}
```

The first way of defining the command \cur (without \xspace) works properly in overleaf and compiles.
However, addition of xspace (second version) breaks the code.
Perhaps at the point inside \tess{} when \cur is called (with xspace) it cannot decide if space has to be added or not and causes problem.

It would be great if somebody can help to solve this issue because I need the normal operation of \cur with the xspace.